# Configural products variable width

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, custom-options, custom

I am setting up a Magento CE store for a friend and have a question regarding product variations.

He sells awnings and sun-blinders to people and have a product with the following specifications:

There are 3 depths for an awning: 2 meters, 3 meters and 4 meters
And multiple sizes in widths, but prices are pr. 50 cm and he want the customer to be able to write the exact measurement in the page.

Example: 2 meter depths and 3,55 m width is calculated down from: 2 meter depths and 4 meter widths. The product is simply cut down from the next possible width size.

I really hope any of you have an idea how to code this up or maybe knows an extension that deals with these type of products.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

You could add a product per cm, where you can only can add these in per 50 base. This is a inventory setting `Qty Increments`

So a customer can add the cm and only per 50cm add to cart.

Depths as simple products and group them in a configurable.
No further coding needed.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this?

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/dynamic-square-foot-pricing-calculator.html

If you want to implement your own extension, the easiest way would be to create a custom option or attribute on a product for the width, have customer enter this width when adding to cart, have the extension calculate the dynamic price, and add the product with a `custom_price` to the cart.

Comment: Thanks for the reply musicliftsme. I had a look at that extension, but thought it only could calculate prices of squarefoot products - this type of products have steps in opposite to a squarefoot price.